# Installing OpenCV

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I am on Mac OSX El Capitan and am trying to install opencv. I am using homebrew with this command.

```
Sumant:Sumant$ brew install opencv
```

The result is `Warning: homebrew/science/opencv 2.4.13.2_1 is already installed`

Even though it says that opencv is already installed, I can't seem to use it with python. Importing cv2 on python gives the error

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

Is opencv different from cv2, if so how do I download cv2 (I already tried to look up questions on stackoverflow but none of those methods work).

Comment: Have you tried to install OpenCV with pip?

Comment: Yes, open cv does not install with pip. It has to be built

Answer (score 2):

There is no real difference. Try the following and you should get going:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 0):

To install both on your Python 2 and Python 3 use:

```
brew install opencv3 --with-contrib --with-python3
```

To install on Python2 only use

```
brew install opencv3 --with-contrib
```

To install on Python 3 only use

```
brew install opencv3 --with-contrib --without-python
```

There is no --with-python2 flag because by default it installs to python2. However, if you want it to go to Python3 you have to add a --with-python3 flag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using anaconda distribution your work will be very easy. Conda installer install most packages seamlessly. For opencv you can try following command after conda installation:

```
conda install -c menpo opencv3
conda install -c menpo opencv
```